# How to get the SMS delivery notification in axis2 sms transport ?

Tags: java, sms, apache-axis, smpp, jsmpp

I'm writing sms api based on axis2 sms transport. I want to know how can i get the sms delivery notification using asix2 sms transport.

**current axis2 sendsms method has no return value**. 
Is JSMPP support sms delivery notification?

Thanks

Comment: DRs are asynchronous low priority notifications so you would not expect a send method to return a delivery status.  The SMSMC will deliver them at some point in the future, catch them with a SMPPListener.

Comment: thanks. @AlexK. Do you have any valuable link ?